# How to bind event on HTML select has multiple attribute when selected in Backbone.js

Tags: html, backbone.js

```
var o = Backbone.View.extend({          
    template: [
        '<label>ok1</label>',
        '<select class="test1"><option>111</option><option>222</option></select>',
        '<label>ok2</label>',
        '<select class="test2" multiple="true" ><option>aaa</option><option>bbb</option><option>ccc</option></select>'
    ].join(''),

    events: {
        'change select': 'foo'
    },

    foo: function(){
        console.log('change');
    }
});
```

The change event work for ok1 when ok1 changed, but when I click the ok2 options, the change event doesn't catch, and I have try many ways to catch the ok2 options selected.
I'm new to backbone.js.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Seems to work as expected http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/4xP6c/

Comment: Thanks, yeah, it seems work fine on jsfiddle, I gonna check my code on my env.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine on jsfiddle like @nikoshr 's  comment, and I don't know why it doesn't work on my env, I change the events to like this:

```
events: {
    'change select': 'foo',
    'click option': 'foo'
},
```

And this work fine for me.